# Installing Linux in Lenovo G40 with Windows in EFI mode

Tags: linux, boot, windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint

I bought a Lenovo G40 and it came with Windows 10 uses UEFI to boot. I am trying to install Linux Mint on an empty partition in order to dual boot. At first I had succeeded. However, after an update, it boots directly into Windows.

I tried reinstalling Linux Mint, but no luck (I get an error at the end of the installation saying that the installation won't boot).

I tried disabling Secure Boot and Fast Startup and then reinstalling Linux Mint. Same thing.

I tried using the Live CD to manually add a "boot" flag to the partition which has the Linux installation. Didn't work as well.

I tried using boot repair, but ended up with [this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753179/bootrepair-doesnt-start-when-trying-to-recover-boot/753214#753214) and no luck.

I read that to properly install Linux in this environment you have to [boot the Live CD into EFI mode](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=163126), and I think this is what I couldn't do. There is no UFI mode boot when I insert the Live CD, and there isn't an option to add this in the BIOS (at least I didn't find it). There following two shots of my BIOS show what appears when I have Legacy mode on and off (both have the same result).

[image]
[image]

Any ideas? Any way that I can boot both in Linux and Windows I'm happy (even if I have to make the dual boot through Windows Boot loader).

Cheers.

Comment: "However, after an update, it boots directly into Windows." - You need use GRUB2 to detect linux installation, just like you would, if you installed Windows after Linux **exact** same principle.

Comment: @Ramhound pardon my ignorance (I'm kind of new to grub and boot still), but I thought that's what I was trying to do with BootRepair and reinstallation of Mint. Can you maybe be more specific (maybe even an answer)? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure the reason you are disabling Secure Boot, Linux Mint, should fully support it.  **"there is no UFI mode boot when I insert the Live CD, and there isn't an option to add this in the BIOS (at least I didn't find it)."**  MBR or GPT partitions, I suspect you might think you have Windows 10 installed in EFI mode but your mistaken.  Of course by "EFI Mode" it simply means NOT enabling legacy/compatability mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I disabled Secure Boot because all the tutorial to install Mint with EFI had that step. I added two pics of my BIOS that might help. That's the main reason I think I have Windows installed in EFI. What do you think?

Comment: The reason your Live installation isn't being displayed is because its missing the required drivers.  Once the required drivers exist on the image it should be displayed.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, you mean when I install Ubuntu through the Live CD I have install some extra drivers? How do I know which drivers to install?

Comment: No; that's not what I am saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38050/discussion-between-tomcho-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Acer Aspire V3 with a similar looking BIOS, InsydeH2O revision 5.0. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674749/acer-aspire-v3-does-not-recognize-my-efi-partition) worked for me.

Comment: Well, I followed step 1, which is to input an Admin Password, but then I couldn't find the `Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing` anywhere. Some ptions then appeared under Legacy Mode, which the Windows Loader, DVDRAM and Network Boot. But I don't know how that helps. I can post a picture if you'd like.

Comment: The boot mode must be UEFI with secure mode enabled. You should not see anything with legacy mode. On my laptop the secure UEFI mode is active by default; you can load the default settings under `Exit` -> `Load Setup Defaults`.

Comment: But under UEFI the only option that appears is the Windows Loader. Setting an admin password didn't change that at all.

Comment: Ok then my solution probably doesn't work with your laptop, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy `shimx64.efi` (or whatever the boot file is on your distribution) to `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` on your EFI partition. [This is the default boot option on many UEFI BIOSes.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1531178) This will not work alongside Windows though since `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` is the default boot file for Windows.

Comment: Thank you, but I really both to be activated.

Comment: I think there should be a way to boot Windows from grub once you have your UEFI loading grub. But I am not sure how it works (I stopped using Windows years ago).